# Alternative to setTimeout for images

Tags: javascript, settimeout

If I want to create a div that is as high a (responsive) image using javascript, I am resorting to setTimeout. For example I might have code like this

```
setTimeout(function(){
    var $imgheight = $('img').height();
    $('.mydiv').height($imgheight);
}, 400);
```

Is there any alternative to this? I know about imagesloaded plugin, is there any simpler alternative?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `load` event to know when the images are loaded:

```
$('img').on('load', function(){
    $('.mydiv').height(this.height);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/083d89me/

Though I don't see the need to set the divs height. Doesn't it adjust itself to the image height by default?

Comment: Yes I tried to simplify my question. let's say I have an image, covered by an overlay div. The overlay div is empty, it just has an opaque background. The image is responsive, so it might be any size.

Answer (score 0):

Well you don't want to create a new div just to change the height of the existing one so please change the description.

Please use the answer from @filur to set the height according to loaded image and then add eventListener for window.resize event :)

```
$(window).on('resize', function(){ ... });
```